# Flutter-> Error: The argument type 'Column' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I just upgrade my flutter version few days ago. Now i got error in `Column` widget.
Here is my error.
[image]

And here is my pubspec.yaml
[image]

**HELP ME TO SOLVE THIS.**

Comment: Try to put that column in `/**/` and place a new empty column at its place. Still get the error?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: Please share complete code instead of screenshots.

Comment: Remove my `children` from `Column` and still having the err.

Answer (score 0):

This error is misleading, just simplify your column as suggested in the comments by stacktrace2234 to see what really is going on.

Did you update it from a non null safety to a null safety dart version?

Comment: flutter --version
Flutter 3.1.0-9.0.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f28e570c8c (12 days ago) • 2022-06-14 13:39:33 -0500
Engine • revision 74ee6b5afd
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-165.1.beta) • DevTools 2.14.0

Comment: Dart SDK version: 2.18.0-165.1.beta (beta) (Mon Jun 13 15:34:45 2022 +0200) on "windows_x64"